# Why is my app crashing while emulating on Android Studio (Kotlin Multiplatform) due to Null ImageView?

Tags: android, kotlin

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

The line this points to is

```
sleepButton.setOnClickListener() {makeCurrentFragmentS(sleepFragment)}
```

where sleepButton is a button within a fragment that someone presses, to open another fragment within a frame layout.

The app has a notification bar which cycles through 3 fragments: home, flight and settings. sleepButton's xml information is on the settings page, while the activity starts on home and this code is contained within MainActivity.kt

Settings (Including sleepButton)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.SettingsFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/SleepButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#FBFBFB"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sleep"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

   </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

In MainActivity, references to sleepButton are as follows:

```
val sleepButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.SleepButton) 
sleepButton.setOnClickListener{makeCurrentFragmentS(sleepFragment)}
```

and the method makeCurrentFragmentS is

```
 private fun makeCurrentFragmentS(fragment: Fragment) =
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.SettingsSwapFLFragment, fragment)
            commit()
        }
```

Comment: Presumably, `sleepButton` is `null`, if the error is coming from that line. It will be unlikely that anyone can help you further without a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question description, thanks!

Comment: "In MainActivity, references to sleepButton are as follows" -- `SleepButton` is not in `MainActivity`. It is in `SettingsFragment`. *Only* reference `SleepButton` from `SettingsFragment`. *Do not* reference `SleepButton` from something else, including the hosting activity or other fragments. Most likely, your `SettingsFragment` has not yet set up its views by the time that you are calling `findViewById()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `sleepButton` `View` is null in your `MainActivity`s `onCreate` method as your fragments layout was not inflated yet. You have to get and manage your `sleepButton` in your fragments `onViewCreated` method:

```
// Inside settings fragment
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val sleepButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.sleep_button)
    sleepButton.setOnClickListener { 
        // Your code
    }
}
```